# using % inside SQLite query with an NSString variable inside the ame quotes

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, sqlite

Here's my code:

```
NSString *vorStatement = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM vor WHERE ident like '%@%'",vorStringSearch];
```

I need to the query to be "SELECT * FROM vor WHERE ident like 'String%'" but it keeps dropping the last % in it so query ends up being "SELECT * FROM vor WHERE ident like 'String'" I tried putting a \ in front of the % and it doesnt work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use '%%' format to escape percent symbol.

```
SELECT * FROM vor WHERE ident like '%@%%'
```