# sqlite - Search with LIKE anywhere in string

Tags: sqlite, cocoa, search, nsstring

Found:

[using % inside SQLite query with an NSString variable inside the ame quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10343749/using-inside-sqlite-query-with-an-nsstring-variable-inside-the-ame-quotes/10343807#10343807)

and this LIKE '%@%%' works if the search string is at the start of the variable.

How to search and find a string anywhere in the variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's standard SQL. You need a `%` on both sides of the search text. So your format string would be `LIKE %%%@%%`.